# Android: Aligning control to center of another control in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have deleted my old and am re-posting my earlier question with more info, since the original question was greatly misjudged.

The below is the original layout. It is a button to the right, and two edit text boxes taking up half the remaining width.

In reality, this is nested within another Linear Layout, but this is the relevant part that I need help with.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtUser"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add" />

    </LinearLayout>


        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/LinInput" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/LinInput"
            android:text="@string/EmptyPass"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:padding="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My objective was to reduce the number of LinearLayouts as suggested in documentations. One possibility is to have an empty view as I have done in the layout below. The empty view had a width equal to the remaining width (minus the button). I have set the two EditText controls on either side of this view.

Now, I just need to figure out how to make the width start from the middle of the view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vwEmptyView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAddPassword"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    </View>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtUser"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/vwEmptyView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/vwEmptyView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAddPassword"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnAddPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnAddPassword" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it should look when rendered.
[image: Android Layout Screen Shot]

BTW, the Hierarchy Viewer shows three greens dots for the other Relative Layout, but this one gets red, red, yellow.

Comment: Your first approach is totally fine. You dont need to remove the `LinearLayout`. Its not that much nested to be avoided. Whatever you are trying is hard to implement without linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could have implemented your required layout with a `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtUser"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/txtPassword"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnAddPassword"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/txtUser"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAddPassword"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnAddPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnAddPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you might have noticed, you do not need any additional view to center the 2 `EditTexts` in the space available. I know the question is about doing the same with a `RelativeLayout`, but I can't think of any way to do that without adding a few unnecessary views. Using a `ConstraintLayout` is the best solution in this case.